# Markers (Google Maps) that causing appearance of new blocks of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to create webpage that initially have only one element exclude footer and header: Google Map with 20 markers. I have 20 pictures and description to them that related to each marker. When it is the first click on marker, it should to pop up the new divs : img and text(description). After that if we click on another marker our new divs must be refreshed to related content.
Is it possible? How can I create this with Google Maps API?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD5yK.jpg

Comment: What you are asking is not difficult but you will have to show some effort before the experts step in and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the marker, add a unique id to that marker, that will later help you identify which marker has been clicked and pick the corresponding image/description for display.

```
        //variable options contains different marker options
        var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(options.lat, options.lng),
            map: myMap,
            draggable: options.draggable || false,
            animation: options.animation || "none",
            icon :  options.markerImage
        });

        myMarker.uniqueID = "myMarkerUniqueID123";

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
             showDetailsAndImage(marker.uniqueID);
        });


        function showDetailsAndImage(id) {
            //do whatever you want to do here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an eventlistener for the markers.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple